# Qual o erro deste código? a animação deve funcionar apenas uma vez

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Eu tenho vários elementos com a classe .track, quando qualquer uma é clicada a div #controls aparece com essa animação, mas preciso que ela só ocorra uma vez. Tentei de várias formas da internet mas não consegui, uma que mais chegou perto fez não repetir ao clicar no mesmo elemento com a classe, mas clicando em outro elemento isso repete. Aqui:

```
       $(document).ready(
function(){
    $(".track").one("click", function () {
        $("#controls").fadeIn()
        .css({bottom:-50,position:'absolute'})
        .animate({bottom:0}, 500, function() {
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O modo mais fácil de solucionar esse problema é utilizando uma variável global, indicando seu já realizou a animação ou não.
Nesse exemplo:

```
var animado = false;
$(document).ready(
function(){
    $(".track").one("click", function () {
        if (animado) {
            return
        }
        animado = true;        
        $("#controls").fadeIn()
        .css({bottom:-50,position:'absolute'})
        .animate({bottom:0}, 500, function() {});
    });
});
```

Assim ele só irá executar a animação na primeira vez.

Comment: Amigo, muito obrigado pela resposta! mas eu testei aqui e não funcionou (o script no geral)... funcionou ai pra ti?

Comment: Desculpe, acabei esquecendo de adicionar um parênteses. Tente de novo :p

Comment: Perfeito amigo!!! muuuuuito obrigado xD